# How to render one section horizontal with others vertical in react native SectionList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I'm implementing a list with the first section vertical and second section horizontal. How do I do that.

I know that I can set the whole sectionlist to horizontal but don't know how to do one particular section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. First you create a `sectionList`. Format the `section` parameter so that the `data` variable is an array of array. When rendering the section list, render each item as a `flatList`.